# When should I use derived in Svelte custom stores?

Tags: svelte

I've followed along with the great Svelte tutorial but I'm having trouble understanding *when* I should use `derived` in my custom stores. In this example, I'm creating a game with 3 states:

- `PRE_GAME`
- `IN_GAME`
- `POST_GAME`

I want to return a boolean check for when I'm in one of those states, and *I think* it would be best on the custom store itself.

This is my current code:

```js
import { writable, derived } from 'svelte/store';

export const gamestate = (() {
  const { set, subscribe } = writable('PRE_GAME');

  return {
    subscribe,
    set
  };
})();

export const preGame = derived(gamestate, ($gamestate) => $gamestate === 'PRE_GAME');
export const inGame = derived(gamestate, ($gamestate) => $gamestate === 'IN_GAME');
export const postGame = derived(gamestate, ($gamestate) => $gamestate === 'POST_GAME');
```

Is it possible to move the derived methods onto the `gamestate` store like `gamestate.preGame()`? Does that make sense to do in Svelte? Then I can call `$gameState` and get whichever value, but also return a boolean check when I need an explicit value.

I expected to be able to do check the internal value without needing to derive its value. Maybe something like below, but it always returns false because `gamestate` is a writable object.

```js
export const createStore = (() {
  const { set, subscribe } = writable('PRE_GAME');

  return {
    subscribe,
    set,
    preGame: () => gamestate === 'PRE_GAME',
    inGame: () => gamestate === 'IN_GAME',
    postGame: () => gamestate === 'POST_GAME',
  };
})();
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom methods on the stores are for how you mutate the state (set and update), but stores generally are only have one getter: the state. And I don't think you want it to be otherwise.

From here on, I see three solutions :

- Make your state an object `{ gameSate: 'PRE_GAME', isPreGame: true, isInGame: false, isPostGame: false }` and then use a custom update function.
- Use derived stores as you did (I see no point in importing derived in the main store or using `get()`).
- Make that calculation in the components, possibly making a dedicated component. Your components would still purely declarative and the only thing mutating still be in the store.

I would decide between just by pure DRYness: imports vs. repeating the clause.

Comment: The other answers work as well, but after trying them out for a little while this _feels_ the most right in Svelte. Deriving from a store in a specific derived function seems to work best.

Answer (score 10):

What you do is return a subscription to a derived store in your custom store:

```js
import { derived, writable } from 'svelte/store'

export const gameState = (() => {
  const store = writable('PRE_GAME')
  const store2 = derived(store, $store => ({
    preGame: $store === 'PRE_GAME',
    inGame: $store === 'IN_GAME',
    postGame: $store === 'POST_GAME'        
  }))
    
  return {
    set: store.set,
    subscribe: store2.subscribe
  }
})()
```

Now when you do `set` on the store it will set the value on *store*, then *store2* will derive new values and the subscribers will react to those changes:

```html
<script>
  import { gameState } from "./store.js"
</script>

<button on:click="{() => $gameState='PRE_GAME'}">go PRE_GAME</button>
<button on:click="{() => $gameState='IN_GAME'}">go IN_GAME</button>
<button on:click="{() => $gameState='POST_GAME'}">go POST_GAME</button>

<br />

{#if $gameState.preGame}
    <span>PRE_GAME</span>
{/if}

{#if $gameState.inGame}
    <span>IN_GAME</span>
{/if}

{#if $gameState.postGame}
    <span>POST_GAME</span>
{/if}
```

---

### Alternative

You can also define different `getters` for each specific state:

```js
import { derived, writable } from 'svelte/store'

export const gameState = (() => {
  const store = writable('PRE_GAME')
    const { set, subscribe } = store

  return {
    set,
    subscribe,
        get preGame() { return derived(store, $store => $store === 'PRE_GAME') },
        get inGame() { return derived(store, $store => $store === 'IN_GAME') },
        get postGame() { return derived(store, $store=> $store === 'POST_GAME') },
  }
})()
```

Now the only problem is that doing `$gameState.preGame` does not exists because that tries to get the *preGame* prop from the content of *$gameState*, and doing `gameState.$preGame` or similar is **invalid syntax**.  To get around that you can destructure the props out of the store where you need them:

```html
<script>
  import { gameState } from './store.js'
  const { preGame, inGame, postGame } = gameState
</script>

<span>Current State: {$gameState}</span>
{#if preGame}<span>PRE_GAME</span>{/if}
{#if inGame}<span>IN_GAME</span>{/if}
{#if postGame}<span>POST_GAME</span>{/if}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I didn’t know you can use stores in store like this. Thank you.

Comment: I like how this looks. Is it possible to do this and also get the $gameState without an explicit get method? When I use derived separately, I can call $gameState and get one of the values. With this $gameState returns [object object] so I needed to add get which returns $store 

Comment: Change store.js `subscribe:store.subscribe,subs: store2` and then you can use both stores in svelte-component `let s=gameState.subs` and `{#if $s.preGame}`

Comment: I added an alternative approach where you export props for each state instead, partially based on the answer from @grohjy you will need to destructure the once you need though (instead of returning three separate props, you can keep them bundled in a second substore of course)

Answer (score 2):

With derived store you can easily have additional variables or values, which are reactive in svelte component. Reactivity can be achieved without derived store, but it’ll be a hacky and ugly solution.

Here is an example of ”forced” reactivity:

store.js:

```
  function createStore() {
      const { set, subscribe } = writable('PRE_GAME');
      let state
      subscribe((v)=>state=v)
      return {
        subscribe,
        set,
        preGame: () => gamestate === 'PRE_GAME',
        inGame: () => state === 'IN_GAME',
        postGame: () => gamestate === 'POST_GAME',
      };
    }
```

App.svelte:

```
<script>
  import {gamestate} from "./store.js"
  $: st=gamestate.inGame($gamestate)
  $: console.log("state", st) 
</script>

<h1 on:click={()=>$gamestate="IN_GAME"}>Hello {$gamestate}!</h1>
<p>state: {st}</p>
```

Some explanations:
`state` -variable holds store status  and it’s updated everytime the store updates, hence we need to subscribe in to our own store. `inGame`-function returns is the state ”IN_GAME” or not.

In app-component we need to create a variable `st` and because it’s created in component it will be reactive. But it’s value is evaluated only by marking it to be observed. Observeable line is made by `$:`, but there is a catch: you need also give the svelte something to observe and therefore there is `$gamestore`-variable as a function parameter. Function don’t need it, but now svelte knows to update this line everytime the `$gamestore` updates.
Here is a REPL:

EDIT: I have updated the REPL to include also the solution mentioned in comment

https://svelte.dev/repl/2991d70689674f50a5fb3e30216d699e?version=3.24.1

You should definitely use a derived store for this kind of reactivity. Derived stores are updated everytime the store, which it is derived from, updates.
But there is also a catch in derived stores. The derived store must be used in component if you want it to be updated ie. you must use somewhere in some svelte component `$derived_store` (auto-subscription) or subscribe manually to derived store

Comment: There is an easier way to have reactive functions inside the store without derived store: define your function `preGame: (state) => state === 'PRE_GAME'` and call it from your component `<p>state2: {gamestate.preGame($gamestate)}</p>` Now you have a reactive variable `$gamestate` in your component and value of the store inside the status-function